# How to get the position of items in TextField in swift

Tags: swift, uitextfield

How to get the position of items in TextField in swift. I have "255.789" text in textField. How can i get the position of "."(decimal point ) in swift.

Comment: And then what you have tried so far to get the position?  
[When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple way you could get it

```
if let t = textField.text
{
  let dotPos = t.rangeOfString(".")?.endIndex.predecessor()
}
```

Just keep in mind the dotPos is an optional that needs to be unwrapped before use

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if let text = textField.text {

  let range = text.rangeOfString(".")

  let index = text.startIndex.distanceTo(range!.startIndex)
  print(index) // 3
}
```

Comment: after trying this i am facing this issue " 'String.index ' does not have member named distanceTo " in   let index = text.startIndex.distanceTo(range!.startIndex)

Comment: what version of swift you are using ? and can you share your code?

Comment: version 6.1.1    
    func textField(textField: UITextField,shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange,replacementString string: String) -> Bool
    {  two digits after decimal
     var str=(textField.text! as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
        var arrayOfString=str.componentsSeparatedByString(".")
        if arrayOfString.count >= 2
        {
            var sepStr=NSString(format:"%@",arrayOfString[1])
            return !(sepStr.length>2)
            
        }
        
        return true
    }

Comment: I am new to swift.. I want that "to allow user to enter only two digits after the decimal in textField"

Comment: @user2253894 `version 6.1.1` Err, no. This *might* be your Xcode version - it's absolutely *not* your Swift version. And if this is your Xcode version, by all means, *update*, the current one is 7.3!